# NSMutableArray index get very high and removeObjectAtIndex at beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, sprite-kit

I am testing and prototyping in SpriteKit and have sprite that I flip with double click. I have 52 sprites in `_theArray`, which holds the names of the sprites currently on the view. When I select a sprite I want it to be on top in the zPosition thread and by achieving that I use the following code to refresh the zPositions for all sprites:

```
- (void)setTheZposition:(NSString *)nodeNameToCheck {

NSLog(@"++setTheZposition:++");

if (![_node.name isEqual: @"background"]) { // Do not react if background
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:nodeNameToCheck usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

        NSUInteger index = [_theArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:
                            ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                return [obj hasPrefix:nodeNameToCheck];
                            }];
        NSLog(@"index: %i & length _theArray: %i", index, [_theArray count]);
        [_theArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [_theArray insertObject:nodeNameToCheck atIndex:0];


        // Refresh the zPosition for all sprites
        float positionZ = (int) [_theArray count];
        for (NSString *theNode in _theArray) {
            SKNode *refreshNode = [self childNodeWithName:theNode];
            refreshNode.zPosition = positionZ;
            positionZ--;
        }
    }];
    }
}
```

The code worked find as long as I only dragged the sprite but when I replace a sprite and remove the original I removing `index = 0` and the adding `index = 0` in `_theArray` and that is what seems to causing the problem.

The crash happen at the following line:

```
[_theArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

...with the index being: `2147483647`

...while it should be `0`.

Crash-log:

```
2013-09-29 21:08:59.445 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] ++setTheZposition:++
2013-09-29 21:08:59.446 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] index: 51 & length _theArray: 52
2013-09-29 21:09:04.112 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] ++setTheZposition:++
2013-09-29 21:09:04.112 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] index: 0 & length _theArray: 52
2013-09-29 21:09:04.343 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] >>>>>>>>T-A-P<<<<<<<<<
2013-09-29 21:09:07.277 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] ++setTheZposition:++
2013-09-29 21:09:07.278 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] index: 0 & length _theArray: 52
2013-09-29 21:09:07.477 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] >>>>>>>>T-A-P<<<<<<<<<
2013-09-29 21:09:10.851 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] ++setTheZposition:++
2013-09-29 21:09:10.851 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] index: 2147483647 & length _theArray: 52
2013-09-29 21:09:10.852 testButtonsetc[11597:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 51]'
```

I would very much appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2147483647 is `NSNotFound`. You should test for `NSNotFound` when using `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`.

Fron the docs:
`enum {NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax};`

`- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate`

Return Value
The lowest index whose corresponding value in the array passes the test specified by predicate. If no objects in the array pass the test, returns `NSNotFound`.

Answer (score 1):

`- indexOfObjectPassingTest:` is returning `NSNotFound`, you need to handle that case.